# In Firebase can I connect a user to multiple tables?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two tables in my Firebase database. In `flighthistory` I record flights that a plane has taken. In `flightperformance` I record how well each plane can perform.

I think there should be a third table with the planes' names and IDs, and that the planes should be assigned their ID in `flighthistory` and `flightperformance`.

Is this the right way to think about coordinating between two tables of data? How can I code this with Firebase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want three tables: 
1: Plane names and ID's. 
2: Flighthistory.
3: Flightperformance.

And instead of having the plane id from table 1 as a foreign key in table 2 and 3 (as it would be in an sql database), you want the same "solution" in firebase?

If so: 
Create a Plane table that holds all the planes. When you create a new plane, the key you will get (by using the getkey()) will be the ID in firebase for that specific plane. You can use the same key as a reference in Flighthistory and Flightperformance to connect the plane with the history and performance tables.

The Firebase "tables" will be like this:

- Plane -> the ID's / keys for each plane -> Plane name and model(maybe?).
- FlightHistory -> You could use the same ID / key here for the plane -> Some flight history data. A good solution here would either be using some kind of an auto increment (Or date + time maybe?), and inside this number, there will be data as in where the plane came from, and the destination.
- Flightperformance -> Same ID here for each plane -> Some flight performance data.

EDIT: A little example of how this could be done:

```
//Get the firebase database reference in onCreate(). For this example, mDatabase will be the databasereference

public void createPlane() {
    //First getting the key which will be used as the reference between the tables
    String key = mDatabase.child("Planes").push().getKey();

    //Create a new plane
    Plane plane = new Plane("Coolplane", "Boeing 777-400");

    //Adding the plane to firebase, with the key as the reference
    mDatabase.child("Planes").child(key).setValue(plane);

    //Starting the methods that create the flighthistory and performance.Passing the key, which will be used as the ID in firebase (which connects the plane with the history and performance
    newFlightHistory(key);
    newPerformance(key);

//Not sure how your history and/or performance table will look like, but you 
just pass the key to these methods, and use these keys as the key when you 
create a new history / performance. 

}
```

NB: As Firebase is a JSON based db, it is usually not a "correct" way to structure the data. It all depends on what queries you are going to use, and how you are going to use the data.

Comment: I like your implementation. Thank you. But what is the "correct" way to structure this data? I basically want the info in `flightHistory` and `flightPerformance` to be updated at different points of time.

Comment: That depends on how you want the system to work. When you start you application, do you get all the data for all the planes into a List? Tell me short how the application will work.

Comment: No, the user will enter planes as time goes on.

Comment: Okay. I'm still not sure exactly how you want the application to work, but the user will enter a plane, and can then add history and/or performance later on?

Comment: EDIT to last post: the user will create a plane* and then add multiple history and/or performance for each of his planes?*

Comment: Remi, yes, you got it.